# genetic Algorithm fitness function for stock market pridiction

Tags: artificial-intelligence

i have been working on stock market prediction for couple of months but could not find any relevant information. i googled it and found some research papers but unfortunately they only mention the working of genetic algorithm. which i already know .

i need to design a fitness function to predict stock market 
i have already get the real data from stock market

`Open     High       Low      Close    Volume`

`253.8    255.8     253.8     255.8    809300`

`250.8      250.8     243.05      247.8    2041000`

`248.1    254.9     248.19        254          4550500`

`254        261.39    252.35      259.54   9926000`

`259.54       260.60    253.5     253.94   5425700`

`253.94       257.25    248.05        256.10   7504500`

`256.1    258.35    248.30    251          10933400`

`251      253.64    249.25    250.44   5478500`

`250.44       252.89    248.60        252.25   6316600`

`252.25       254.85   252    254.05   6332500`

`254.05       255.35   252    252.25   6961600`

`253.5    259.5    253.5      259.25   10216200`

`259.25       260.20   257.10     257.89   6071400`

can anyone please help me to get a relevant fitness function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your fitness function would be how close your predictions were to the actual. So you've got your population of agents who are predicting tomarrow's prices. Like, agent #12683 goes through his model and predicts that the price of eggs will be up 0.5% tomorrow. You take their predictions (+0.5%), subtract them from the actual prices, and take the absolute. 
A score of zero is perfect.

You'd use historical data to provide a learning set on.

And you'd be a decade behind the quant-devs who have already done this and a few years behind the quant-devs who gamed those systems to make a buck. Welcome to the stock market.